# Multiple sites on IIS running the exact same code and configuration - some of them put w3wp.exe to 100%, some are fine

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, iis

Everything worked fine a few days ago. I *think* everything worked perfectly fine till I tried to create an AMI of this EC2 instance. It *appears* that the creation attempt caused the server to become non-responsive, so I stopped that process and restarted the server. It's Windows Server 2008 R2, running 6 ASP sites and 6 PHP sites. All PHP sites identical, all ASP sites identical.

On some of the sites, they load fast and without incident. Some of them put W3WP to 100% and they just don't load, eventually throwing a 500 error and subsequent refreshes say the site is unavailable. (Sometimes - I just tried again and got no unavailable errors, but still got  500 after the server timed out)

None of this makes sense to me, they should all load the same and they shouldn't have been effected by any of this. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Have a look at the answers to [W3WP.EXE using 100% CPU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052633/w3wp-exe-using-100-cpu-where-to-start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the IIS config reverted and put some PHP sites to ASP, and all ASP sites weren't working. ASP wasn't working because the data it was expecting to loop through from MySQL wasn't there, somehow the SQL config got corrupted as well. So basically my issue was I needed to re-configure SQL so ASP would load, and re-configure IIS to point my php sites to php.